Is it possible to forward usb via rdp from windows to linux?
I have windows PC, usb drive, default rdp client "Remote desktop connection".
Also ubuntu with rdp server xrdp.
I tried to connect to rdp server with forwarding usb via specifing local devices like in this example. But do not see usb device after connect (via lsusb for example).
Is it possible to forward usb from windows to linux via rdp? Or it works only for windows to windows connection?
